# Difference between a UX designer and a Concept designer?

Tags: professionalism

These terms have only popped up relatively recently, and I've been doing this sort of stuff before they were around, so have been at a bit of a loss now as to what to call my job description. I design app concepts, structures and flow, know a bit about coding and a bit about graphic design, as well as a bit about sociology/psychology.

UI Designer, I gather, is a person who actually draws, say, buttons and switches in an app.

Concept designer does wireframes, decides how the flow and organization of the app should go, and streamlines bottlenecks. Doesn't necessarily draw anything.

UX designer...does the same thing? Or does a UX designer also draw the UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your descriptions for these positions are actually correct. I suggest you Google them and look on Wikipedia to get a more concrete idea of what it is they do, but I'll summarise the important differences:

- User interface designers are chiefly concerned with designing how someone interacts with software. Their main focus is in *design*, which may involve drawing things but may also involve coding the interface, or doing neither and just focusing on creating specifications in the form of wireframes or other forms.
- Concept designers aren't used in software as much as they are in fields like 3d modeling or animation, but their focus lies in visualising a concept and communicating it to stakeholders. This might mean proficiency in 3d modeling or animation tools depending on how they want to communicate the idea, or it might mean not using software at all and just presenting sketches to a client or team.
- User experience designers perform a high-level, multidisciplinary role ensuring the quality of the product experience by the end user group. That means they can be involved in product design, quality assurance, user interface design, marketing, customer support, usability testing, copywriting, programming (performance testing!), prototyping and a bunch of other related fields, all from the point of view of making sure the user experience is designed well.

So the difference between a concept designer and a UX designer is quite large. Specifically, concept designers are responsible for the conceptual phase. UX designers remain responsible from inception throughout a product lifecycle. Yes, UX designers can draw UIs, but that's not generally their whole responsibility.

If you're a concept designer doing wireframes and deciding how the app should work, you're probably a user interface designer. If you do both concept and implementation, you might be a UX designer. If you also do programming, you might be [a fabled unicorn](http://www.jeffgothelf.com/blog/unicorn-a-visual-designer-with-ux-chops/)!

Personally I tend to view "titles" as role descriptions which are contextual and can change. For instance, sometimes I take on the role of product designer when designing the product I work on. It's as general as possible to describe what I do on a daily basis. And other times other roles better describe what I do. Don't sweat it too much; focus on doing what you love well first.

Comment: I have googled this, but it seems that, as with "social media guru", everyone is a UX designer these days, which muddies the waters a bit.. :)

Comment: [Not necessarily a bad thing](http://blog.handcraft.com/2011/08/dont-stop-calling-yourself-a-ux-designer-its-working/)...

Comment: I certainly prefer this web/software environment with "too many" UX designers to the practically pre-UX environment of the early 90s =p